# How to paginate a list with python django

Tags: python, django, pagination

I have a code that call a rest-full service that return a list,i want make the  pagination but i have some problems.

this is my code:

```
results = requests.get(url)
col = results.json()
page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
paginator = Paginator(tuple(col), 10)
try:
    proc = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    proc = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    proc = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```

When i run my code the variable `proc` does not have any information.

**Note:**
I noted the service return a pagination, for that my code don't work. I change the service and now the service only send the list, and my code work. But if i want that my service send the pagination how i can receive and manage the pagination in my code.

Comment: `page` has data in it?

Comment: are using `proc.object_list` to access the information?